# Semantic content Attribute

Tags: swift

In my current project I need to switch the language form English to Arabic, and for that I am using semantic content attribute. Is there is any way to apply this semantic content attribute to a particular view controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Localize_Swift](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) and extension like this

```
extension Localize {
    
    static var isRTL: Bool {
        return Localize.currentLanguage() == "ar"
    }
    
    static var semanticContent: UISemanticContentAttribute {
        return isRTL ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
    }
    
    static var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment {
        return isRTL ? .right : .left
    }
    
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = Localize.semanticContent
        
        return true
    }
```

Also

**BaseViewController.swift**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = Localize.semanticContent
   
    }
```